# C# - Emgu CV -Can i use Emgu cv on a Console Application?

Tags: c#, winforms, console-application, desktop-application, emgucv

Can I develop an application that is not Windows form, i.e. that is Console application using EMGU CV? I want to do the image processing on the desktop using C# and Emgu CV and send the result to an Android via Http. Can I do it as a console application using Emgu CV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can use console application. EmguCV acts as a standard library.

For your problem I would suggest that you write WebService or WebApplication that will run on a server. I think you could use that with a IIS server. For Apache you needed to compile opencv and EmguCV for Linux and then install mod_mono for Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can e.g.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Image<Hsv, byte> bitmap = new Image<Hsv, byte>(@"D:\red3.bmp");
            Image<Hsv, byte> bitmap1 = new Image<Hsv, byte>(@"D:\testc.bmp");
            Image<Hsv, byte> bitmapDIFF = bitmap - bitmap1;
            Hsv lowerLimit = new Hsv(0, 0, 200);
            Hsv upperLimit = new Hsv(5, 255, 255);

            var imageHSVDest = bitmap.InRange(lowerLimit, upperLimit);

            //CvInvoke.cvShowImage("imageHSVDest", imageHSVDest);

           CvInvoke.cvShowImage("imageHSVDest",bitmapDIFF);

            bitmap.AbsDiff(bitmap1);
            CvInvoke.cvWaitKey(0);

        }
    }
```